# mod_tls missing on proftpd

Tags: debian, ssl, proftpd

I am trying to enable TLS on Proftpd server (ProFTPD Version 1.3.7a, Debian version: 11)

However, after completing all the steps and restarting the proftpd I am getting the below error.

```
mod_dso/0.5: unable to load 'mod_tls.c'; check to see if '/usr/lib/proftpd/mod_tls.la' exists
```

So I checked the /usr/lib/proftpd/ and the mod_tls is missing there. How can I enable/install this module there?

Proftpd is installed via apt-get install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install it with this command: `apt install proftpd-mod-crypto`.

Answer (score 0):

For Debian 11 I was saved by uncommenting "LoadModule mod_tls.c" in "/etc/proftpd/modules.conf".